# files don't contain c extensions

Tags: unix

How can I find name of files and directories from `ls` command using egrep that don't have `.c` extension.

For example if ls command result is

```
a bb ccc a.c bb.c
```

then the output must be

```
a bb ccc
```

Answer (score 2):

`find` will help you:

```
find . -not -name '*.c'
```

if you want to restrict it to the current directory:

```
find . -not -name '*.c' -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: Thanks.How can I find name of files or directories which have max four characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
shopt -s extglob

ls !(*.c)
```